# Is there a publicly available API that does time zone conversion?

Tags: language-agnostic, timezone

Does anyone provide an 3rd party API that does time zone conversions? I'm thinking of doing it for a site, just to make it easier to handle all the intricacies. It is a multi-zone scheduling kind of applicaiton and time zones need to be handled perfectly.

I dont think timeanddate.com does it, but does anyone else? Reliabily?

Comment: Most modern languages should come with the necessary functionality built-in. It may be a little more work to grok how it works once, but should be vastly preferred to calling a web service every time. No?

Comment: Hi dece - not exactly... you're right and we're currently doign that (home-grown solution), but ours is kind of like a scheduling applicaiton across borders and timezones + daylight savings, etc lead to a bit of a mess! :) Just exploring options to "offshore" it a bit!

Comment: What language/framework/environment are you using that can't reliably and reasonably simply convert between timezones?

Comment: Hi dece - we're using php, but the issue is _not_ php, but the fact that we get so muddled that we dont know what is what! We need to manage 'static' times, 'availability' times, across events which repeat for many days (including crossing over daylight saving change-over days), and of course, for all the countries of the world...

Comment: Then converting the time doesn't seem to be the problem you're trying to solve. Whether you convert it "in-house" or use a 3rd party to do the conversion, you'll still have to sort out the messy internal handling...

Comment: ....I dont know about that! I really want a simple function where I give it a certain time and date (in a timezone) and tell it what timezone I want it in - and it should give me the exact date and time in the target zone! Yes of course this is possible internally, but I fear getting it wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few just searching on google, such as this one:

http://worldtimeengine.com/api/instructions

There seem to be some for a variety of languages, it depends on your need I guess as I'm not sure if you are trying to do it based on city or what

Comment: paid options are fine, but we're looking for a _simpler_ timezone converting service... and which is reliable / running for some time...

Answer (score 1):

> I really want a simple function where I give it a certain time and date (in a timezone) and tell it what timezone I want it in - and it should give me the exact date and time in the target zone! Yes of course this is possible internally, **but I fear getting it wrong!**

Then you need to test, test and test more. If you're outsourcing because you're afraid of programming you should just buy some software. ;P

The function itself is simple enough.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php

```
function convertTimeZone($time, $origin, $target) {
    $date = new DateTime($time, new DateTimeZone($origin));
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($target));
    return $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}

echo convertTimeZone('2000-01-01 00:00:00', 'Pacific/Nauru', 'Pacific/Chatham');
```

Comment: this doesn't works when dealing with daylight savings.

Answer (score 0):

While googling I found this API Service- www.timezdb.com.
It just takes parameters as latitude, longitude, city name, state, country name. I don't know what exactly you require, but just you can visit and see if it could solve your purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Something I made a while ago gives you all timezones, their current time, and if DST is active there or not:

http://api.coronatus.com/clock/read

You can use the `utc_offset` field to do timezone conversions.